# How to remap a few keys for chrome/google docs?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I'm using Cmd-Option-1 .. Cmd-Option-5 to go to different desktops, on Moutain Lion.

Besides changing my global defaults, how else could I enable the google doc shortcuts for Cmd-Option- to set a paragraph style?

I want some sort of program that will take Ctrl-Option- in chrome and send chrome Cmd-Option-num (and not change desktops).

Answer (score 1):

The only option I can think of would be to change the default shortcuts to something like ⌃⌥⇧⌘+numbers and save this as [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) in KeyRemap4MacBook.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
<item>
<name>test</name>
<identifier>private.test</identifier>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::KEY_1, VK_OPTION | VK_COMMAND, KeyCode::KEY_1, VK_CONTROL | VK_OPTION | VK_SHIFT | VK_COMMAND</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::KEY_2, VK_OPTION | VK_COMMAND, KeyCode::KEY_2, VK_CONTROL | VK_OPTION | VK_SHIFT | VK_COMMAND</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::KEY_3, VK_OPTION | VK_COMMAND, KeyCode::KEY_3, VK_CONTROL | VK_OPTION | VK_SHIFT | VK_COMMAND</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::KEY_4, VK_OPTION | VK_COMMAND, KeyCode::KEY_4, VK_CONTROL | VK_OPTION | VK_SHIFT | VK_COMMAND</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::KEY_5, VK_OPTION | VK_COMMAND, KeyCode::KEY_5, VK_CONTROL | VK_OPTION | VK_SHIFT | VK_COMMAND</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::KEY_6, VK_OPTION | VK_COMMAND, KeyCode::KEY_6, VK_CONTROL | VK_OPTION | VK_SHIFT | VK_COMMAND</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::KEY_7, VK_OPTION | VK_COMMAND, KeyCode::KEY_7, VK_CONTROL | VK_OPTION | VK_SHIFT | VK_COMMAND</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::KEY_8, VK_OPTION | VK_COMMAND, KeyCode::KEY_8, VK_CONTROL | VK_OPTION | VK_SHIFT | VK_COMMAND</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::KEY_9, VK_OPTION | VK_COMMAND, KeyCode::KEY_9, VK_CONTROL | VK_OPTION | VK_SHIFT | VK_COMMAND</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::KEY_0, VK_OPTION | VK_COMMAND, KeyCode::KEY_0, VK_CONTROL | VK_OPTION | VK_SHIFT | VK_COMMAND</autogen>
</item>
<item>
<name>test2</name>
<identifier>private.test2</identifier>
<only>GOOGLE_CHROME</only>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::KEY_1, VK_CONTROL | VK_OPTION, KeyCode::KEY_1, VK_OPTION | VK_COMMAND</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::KEY_2, VK_CONTROL | VK_OPTION, KeyCode::KEY_2, VK_OPTION | VK_COMMAND</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::KEY_3, VK_CONTROL | VK_OPTION, KeyCode::KEY_3, VK_OPTION | VK_COMMAND</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::KEY_4, VK_CONTROL | VK_OPTION, KeyCode::KEY_4, VK_OPTION | VK_COMMAND</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::KEY_5, VK_CONTROL | VK_OPTION, KeyCode::KEY_5, VK_OPTION | VK_COMMAND</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::KEY_6, VK_CONTROL | VK_OPTION, KeyCode::KEY_6, VK_OPTION | VK_COMMAND</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::KEY_7, VK_CONTROL | VK_OPTION, KeyCode::KEY_7, VK_OPTION | VK_COMMAND</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::KEY_8, VK_CONTROL | VK_OPTION, KeyCode::KEY_8, VK_OPTION | VK_COMMAND</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::KEY_9, VK_CONTROL | VK_OPTION, KeyCode::KEY_9, VK_OPTION | VK_COMMAND</autogen>
<autogen>--KeyToKey-- KeyCode::KEY_0, VK_CONTROL | VK_OPTION, KeyCode::KEY_0, VK_OPTION | VK_COMMAND</autogen>
</item>
</root>
```

See the source for the [keycode constants](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data/KeyCode.data) and [predefined settings](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/Tests/lib/string/data/checkbox.xml?raw=true).

Comment: If this is done, will the Cmd-Opt-Num key still work to switch desktops?

Comment: Yeah, that's what the first group is for.